# use JWT Bearer token in swagger Laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt, swagger

i am using L5-swagger from DarkaOnLine for my project. I want to use JWT Auth in my documentation. I have added this code :

```
/**
  @OAS\SecurityScheme(
      securityScheme="API Key Auth",
      type="apiKey",
      in="header",
      name="Authorization",
  )
 **/
```

In swagger UI the "Authorize" button is showed and there is a form to fill with token. But after i enter it, i still got "token_not_provided" error in function that need token to access it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`@OAS` annotations are for OpenAPI 3.0, where Bearer authentication is defined as `type: http` + `scheme: bearer`:

```
/**
  @OAS\SecurityScheme(
      securityScheme="bearerAuth",
      type="http",
      scheme="bearer"
  )
 **/
```

Make sure your operations use `security` with the same name as specified in `securityScheme="<NAME>"` above. For example:

```
/**
 * @OAS\Get(
 *   ...
 *   security={{"bearerAuth":{}}}
 *   ...
```

In Swagger UI's "Authorize" dialog, enter the token without the "Bearer" prefix.

Comment: it works now, but i changed type="bearer" to scheme="bearer"

Comment: Yes it should be `scheme="bearer"` of course. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 11):

this link solved my problem.
[Bearer Authorization setup](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume/issues/70#issuecomment-489388479)

I used this for **Laravel Lumen, JWT** authentication.

---

Add this somewhere in your middleware or any other place like base controller

```
/**
 * @OA\SecurityScheme(
 *     type="http",
 *     description="Login with email and password to get the authentication token",
 *     name="Token based Based",
 *     in="header",
 *     scheme="bearer",
 *     bearerFormat="JWT",
 *     securityScheme="apiAuth",
 * )
 */
```

And add this to your action/function.

```
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *  path="/resources",
 *  summary="Get the list of resources",
 *  tags={"Resource"},
 *  @OA\Response(response=200, description="Return a list of resources"),
 *  security={{ "apiAuth": {} }}
 * )
 */
```

Answer (score 10):

You could modify the swagger config to look like this. i.e config/l5-swagger.php

```
'bearer_token' => [ // Unique name of security
   'type' => 'apiKey', // Valid values are "basic", "apiKey" or "oauth2".
   'description' => 'Enter token in format (Bearer <token>)',
   'name' => 'Authorization', // The name of the header or query parameter to be used.
   'in' => 'header', // The location of the API key. Valid values are "query" or "header".
],
```

Then add modify your operations to look like this.

```
    /**
     * @OA\Get(
     * ...
     *     security={{"bearer_token":{}}}
     * ...
     * )
     */
```

Notice the `bearer_token` used here is the same as Unique name of the security.
With this approach, you do not need to make changes to the middleware.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, after running `php artisan vendor:publish --provider "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"` to generate the Swagger configuration file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hi There here is my solution
Steps
1 - Open the file l5-swagger.php and add the config as below config/l5-swagger.php
[image]
2 -  run this command php artisan vendor:publish --provider "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"
[image]
3 - Add  security={{"bearer_token":{}}},
[image]
4 - php artisan l5-swagger:generate

5 - Login and copy the token as below
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Sangtum API authentication.

In file `config/l5-swagger.php` uncomment sanctum default security configuration.

```php
'sanctum' => [ // Unique name of security
     'type' => 'apiKey', // Valid values are "basic", "apiKey" or "oauth2".
     'description' => 'Enter token in format (Bearer <token>)',
     'name' => 'Authorization', // The name of the header or query parameter to be used.
     'in' => 'header', // The location of the API key. Valid values are "query" or "header".
],
```

Then run command below:

```bash
 php artisan vendor:publish --provider "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"
```

Then for your protected function, you can use sanctum security.

```php
/**
  * @OA\Get(
  *     path="/path",
  *     tags={"Tag"},
  *     description="description",
  *     security={{"sanctum":{}}},
  *     ...
  * )
  */
```

Regenerate your documentation with command below:

```bash
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
```

Then you can press the Authentication button and inside input set your Bearer token in format `Bearer <your token>`